# onclick open a popup window and specify the dimensions of an image to create it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to open a popup window on-click on an image and let user to give dimensions of that particular image. So that the image will create accordingly to the given height and width values. I've searched a lot but couldn't find a way to start. Any idea?? :)

Thanks

Comment: You want to open a new window on clicking of an image.. what is it you want after that? And what have you tried ?

Comment: @putvande- not actually to open a new window. i wanted to pop up a prompt window in order to set dimensions of an image. Then the image should change according to the given dimension values. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you're after. Hence, deal with my imagination!

Click on the image and on the prompt window, enter the values in **`WIDTHxHEIGHT`** format to see the image being resized.

```js
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", function() {

    var dims = prompt("Enter image dimensions", "100x100");
    
    if (!/^\d{2,}x\d{2,}$/i.test(dims)) {
        alert ("Invalid format!");
        return;
    }

    this.width = dims.split('x')[0] || 'auto';
    this.height = dims.split('x')[1] || 'auto';
});
```

```html
<img src="http://butterfly-conservation.org/files/peacock-matt-berry.jpg" />
```

And a jQuery solution as well, just in case:

```
$("img").on("click", function() {

    var dims = prompt("Enter image dimensions", "100x100");

    if (!/^\d{2,}x\d{2,}$/i.test(dims)) {
        alert ("Invalid format!")
    }

    $(this).css({
        width: dims.split('x')[0] || 'auto',
        height: dims.split('x')[1] || 'auto'
    });
});
```